# How to create a 3x3 grid, using opencv2 or PILLOW. similar to TIC-TAC-TOE?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0, python-imaging-library, tic-tac-toe, sudoku

I want to generate a 3x3 grid, in which one of the 9 grids highlighted each time. so that I will get 9 different images. for example: 3rd image would be look like this. It is okay to use any library, PIL or cv2 are mostly preffered. Any help is greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: Just draw a bunch of rectangles... `cv2.rectangle(...)`. Btw, this is a 3x3 grid

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

im = Image.new('RGB', (300,300), (255,255,255))
dr = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        # dr.rectangle(((0+(j)*100,0+(j)*100),(100+(j)*100, 100+(j)*100)), fill="blue", outline = "black")
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        print([(0+i*100,0+j*100),(100+i*100,100+j*100)])
        dr.rectangle([(0+j*100,0+i*100),(100+j*100,100+i*100)], fill="blue", outline = "black")
        im.show()
```